# Restore First Image after an animation with spriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When the function detect collision between my player and the bomb, i animate the explosion's images but my bomb stay on the last one and do not reset to the first image of the bomb (the bomb stay to the last image of the explosion)

how i can reset it ?

Thank you a lot

```
// Contact Between Player and the Bomb

    if ( body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Rock ) {


        let time = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.20)

        // Play sound of explosion
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explosion.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

        //explosion image
        let explosion = SKAction.run(){

            let p0 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe")
            let p1 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe2")
            let p2 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe3")
            let p3 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe4")
            let p4 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe5")
            let p5 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe6")
            let p6 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe7")
            let p7 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe8")
            let p8 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe10")

            let frame: [SKTexture] = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8]

            let animations = SKAction.animate(with: frame, timePerFrame: 0.1)
            self.rock.run(SKAction.repeat(animations, count: 1))


        }

        // Move Player position Backward -30
        let playerPosition = SKAction.run(){


            self.player.position.x += -30


        }



        self.run(SKAction.sequence([sound, explosion, time, playerPosition]))

    }
```

Comment: What is "p0" and where do you use it. Maybe you can add it in the beginning and end?

Answer (score 2):

First off I would not set-up the animations within didBeginContact... there's no reason to be doing this every single time a contact is made. It's probably going to cause weird behavior.

Make a texture atlas object. 
Set-up your animations somewhere else.

From Xcode:

"An SKTextureAtlas object is a collection of related texture objects either created from a texture atlas stored inside the app bundle or **created at runtime.** **Texture atlases can improve memory usage and rendering performance.** **Whenever you have textures that are always used together, store them in an atlas.** "

E.g create a stored property for your GameScene or Rock class... whatever makes most sense. If you do it in the Rock class... adjust the code as needed though. Mine assumes GameScene.

var explodeAction:SKAction?

---

Create an animation set-up function that stores that explode action. And don't forget p0 if you wanted it in the animation. If (for animations) restore is true, it will go back to the initial texture.

```
func setUpExplodeAnimation() {
        var atlasTextures = [SKTexture]()

        let p0 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe")
        let p1 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe2")
        let p2 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe3")
        let p3 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe4")
        let p4 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe5")
        let p5 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe6")
        let p6 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe7")
        let p7 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe8")
        let p8 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "bombe10")

// Note: I'm guessing p0 should be in here... so I added it. You left it out in your version. Decide if it should be a frame in the animation //

       let frame: [SKTexture] = [p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8]

       for texture in frame {
           atlasTextures.append(texture)
       }


// By setting restore to true. When the action completes, the sprite’s texture is restored to the texture it had before the action completed //

// Also for resize . If true, the sprite is resized to match each new texture. If false, the size of the sprite remains at a constant size. //

// You want it to repeat so the first runthrough restore is false. 
        let animationRun1 = SKAction.animate(with: atlasTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: false)

// restore is true so it goes back to initial texture on the 2nd runthrough // 

        let animationRun2 = SKAction.animate(with: atlasTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true)

        let seq = SKAction.sequence( [ animationRun1, animationRun2] )
        explodeAction = self.run(seq)

    }
```

---

Note: You'll need to call setUpExplodeAnimation() in GameScene() didMove(to view: SKView) so it's set-up when loading. That way explodeAction has a value.

---

Now your didBegin function looks like this

```
// Contact Between Player and the Bomb

    if ( body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Rock ) {


        let time = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.20)

        // Play sound of explosion
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explosion.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

        // Move Player position Backward -30
        let playerPosition = SKAction.run(){


           self.player.position.x += -30


        }



        self.run(SKAction.sequence([sound, explodeAction, time, playerPosition]))

    }
```

---

You may want to add an if statement or someway of preventing your code in didBegin from firing more than once. I find didBeginContact often accidently fires more than once. 
So this might prevent that.

Create a GameScene stored property called

var explodeActionRunning: Bool = false

Then in your didBegin

```
// Contact Between Player and the Bomb

    if ( body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Rock ) {


        let time = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.20)

        // Play sound of explosion
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explosion.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

        // Move Player position Backward -30
        let playerPosition = SKAction.run(){
            self.player.position.x += -30
        }

       let explodeActionStart = SKAction.run{
            self.explodeActionRunning = true
        }

       let explodeActionDone = SKAction.run{
            self.explodeActionRunning = false
        }

   // if statement prevents sequence from running twice. //
        if !self.explodeActionRunning {
                 self.run(SKAction.sequence([explodeActionStart, sound, explodeAction, time, playerPosition, explodeActionDone]))
        }

    }
```

---

Let me know if this helps or if anything doesn't make sense / doesn't work. 
I may have made a typo or two.

Comment: i have a mistake on the screen :(explodeAction = self.rock/run(seq) ) ==> "Cannot assign value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to type 'SKAction?' " .

Comment: You may want to put the explode code I wrote in your rock class instead of GameScene. I edited my code answer to get rid of .rock. ... I have no idea why you used .rock.  So when you use it is up to you. Maybe ....Try explodeAction = self.run(seq).

Comment: In fact the animation code and action stored property may make more sense in your rock class if the rock is the thing that's exploding and the texture that is changing. Place the code in the class that makes sense... I just used GameScene for examples sake....My point was to illustrate the need to separate your animation.

Comment: Also ... I'm assuming you didn't write ... self.rock/run(seq)   ....The forward slash / is obviously wrong. It should be self.rock.run(seq)